# What is a negative inversion?

Tags: geometry, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

In a solution to the problem, [IMO 2015 #3](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1112748p5079655) Evan Chen and Telv Cohl
used the notation of negative inversion which looks like Homothety:

[image]

[image]

Here , $\angle$$AML$=$\angle ABL=\angle AKL$.

Also,$H, J$ are the midpoints of $BC, AC$.$D, E, F$ are the feet of the perpendiculars drawn from$C, A, B$ to their opposite sides.$I$ is the orthocenter of this triangle.

Now, if I perform a negative inversion , then what will happen to the circles passing through the center? also, what will happen to the lines not passing through the center?

Can this inversion take the $\odot(ABC)$ to its nine-point circle? As the plain inversion around the circle with center$O$ sends point $P$ to $P'$ so that $OP$$\times$$OP'=r^2$ where r is the radius of the circle we are inverting around.

How do actually negative inversion map the points?

Comment: How exactly did Chen and Cohl use "negative inversion"? Can you link to the source?

Comment: here is the link https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1112748p5079655

Comment: Inversion with "pole" (= center) $I$ and "power" $k$ maps a point $P$ onto a point $P'$ (and reciprocally) if $I,P,P'$ aligned with $\vec{IP'}\cdot \vec{IP}=k$ (here with $k < 0$) contrasting with $\vec{IP'}=k\vec{IP}$ for a homothety which is very different.

Comment: @Jean Marie, yes I know this property of natural Inversion. But what do you think about negative inversion?

Comment: My comment was in reaction with your first sentence "which looks like a homothety".

Comment: I have taken the liberty to include in your question the reference and even the solution by Cohl.

Comment: @ Jean marie,Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Negative inversion is inversion in a circle with an imaginary radius.  For example, the circle $x^2+y^2=-r^2$ has radius $ir$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Such "imaginary" circles exist, in the same sense that the "imaginary" number $i$ exists, and you can work with them using the same algebra as for real circles.

Whereas inversion in a real circle with radius $r$ takes $P\to P'$ so that $OP\times OP'=r^2$, inversion in an imaginary circle satisfies $OP\times OP'=-r^2$.  i.e. $P$ and $P'$ are in opposite directions from center $O$.

It follows that negative inversion is "regular" inversion followed by a reflection in $O$.

See also [cut-the-knot](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Inversion2.shtml)

Comment: I approve he explanation of composition of an inversion  with power $|k|$ with a symmetry with respect to the pole of inversion. But I don't consider "inversion in an imaginary circle" as  a useful image.

Comment: @Jean Marie, you are probably right that Imaginary circles are not helpful in a math contest context, but I'm a fan and couldn't resist.